# OpenERP - widget image readonly

Tags: python, image, widget, odoo, readonly

I need that a widget image (defined as a binary field in model) behaves like a readonly field, but it doesn't. I have defined the field as readonly in the model and in the view, but when entering in "edit mode", the image lets you to upload a file as if it were editable.

Is there a way to fix this ?

Thank you in advance,

Pablo Carballo.

Answer (score 0):

Problem resolved !! In the file base.xml from the path: /addons/web/static/src/xml/, i added below the tag `<t t-name="FieldBinaryImage">`, a t-if tag that controls if the field is not readonly before letting edit the image.

Here is the chunk of code that contains the line added:

```
<t t-name="FieldBinaryImage">
   <span class="oe_form_field oe_form_field_image" t-att-style="widget.node.attrs.style">
  <!-- the following is the line I added: -->
 <t t-if="!widget.get('effective_readonly')">
    <div class="oe_form_field_image_controls oe_edit_only">
        <t t-call="HiddenInputFile">
            <t t-set="fileupload_id" t-value="widget.fileupload_id"/>
            Edit 
        </t>
        <div class="oe_form_binary_progress" style="display: none">
            <img t-att-src='_s + "/web/static/src/img/throbber.gif"'     width="16" height="16"/>
            <b>Uploading ...</b>
        </div>
    </div>
</t>
</span>
</t>
```